# How to prevent the white border after convert with ghostscript

Tags: linux, shell, ghostscript

i try to convert an .eps File to .png with ghostscript.

The .eps file has a resolution of 1000x1000 px. But the outfile has big white borders on left and on the bottom side.

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -r1000x1000 -q -sDEVICE=png256 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=880 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=720 -sOutputFile=infile.png infile.eps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPS files don't have a resolution, so it cannot possibly have a resolution of 1000x1000, especially not 1000x1000 *pixels*, because that's not a resolution, its a size.

I very  much doubt you want to set the resolution to 1000 dpi and at the same time set a media size of 880 points x720 points. That will result in a .png 12000x10000 pixels. (There are 72 points to the inch, which means you are setting a media of 12x10 inches at 1000 doits per inch)

The correct way to handle an EPS file (which is slightly but importantly different to a PostScript file) is to arrange the scaling yourself.

If the dimensions of the resulting image are not important to you, then you can use -dEPSCrop which will produce an image where the dimensions of the media are taken from the comments in the EPS file.

If you require that the image has specific dimensions then you should use -g to set the media size (in pixels), set -dFIXEDMEDIA and set -dEPSFitPage which will scale the EPS to fit the dimensions of the media.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution : 
-dEPSCrop

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing that without seeing the `eps` file, but you can trim it off with `ImageMagick` like this:

```
convert SomeFile.png -trim result.png
```

`ImageMagick` is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX, and Windows.

Comment: Imagemagick is not a good program. It creats a lot of garbage in /tmp and deletes the old version . but i found the solution with the option -dEPSCrop